# Editing joined tables in php/sql

Tags: php, sql, join

I have two tables

- workorder
- customers

I am working on creating workorders using the customers table. I want a page that searches the customers table from within the workorders table, and displays the corresponding workorder.

For instance, search the `name` field of workorder (which is a number linking to customers), and display the results of the search.

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();

$q = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($q) {
    $sql = 'SELECT workorder.id, FName, LName, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers ON customers.id=workorder.name; 
    SELECT FName, LName FROM customers SELECT name FROM workorder, WHERE name=FName/LName and FName/LName = '%$q%' ORDER BY workorder.id;';

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['FName'] ." ".$row['LName']; '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['installer'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['salesman'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['category'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['status'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td width=250>';
        echo '<a class="btn" href="readworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
else {

    $sql = 'SELECT workorder.id, FName, LName, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers ON customers.id=workorder.name';
    $rows = $pdo->query($sql);
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['FName'] ." ".$row['LName']; '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['installer'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['salesman'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['category'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['status'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td width=250>';
        echo '<a class="btn" href="readworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
Database::disconnect();
```

Form search code :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find Workorder" class="btn btn-success"/>
</form>
```

[image: Example]

@Diogo Ferraz here is my insert code, edited by your guidance :

```
if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO workorder (date, installer, salesman, category, status) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
            INSERT INTO workorder (name) SELECT customers.id FROM customers;";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($date,$installer,$salesman,$category,$status));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: workorders.php");
        }
```

This adds four entries into my workorder table, the first of which no customer id information is transferred into the table, 3 more of which the customer id is transferred as needed.

This is what I need :

The value "$id" that is transferred from the prior page(the customer id) to be inserted into the table code with the other form submissions.  Psuedocode for this is as follows(for an example of what I need)

$id = 35(customer.id)
$id = workorder.name
$sql = "INSERT INTO workorder ($id, date, installer, salesman, category, status) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, that which you need is a form to search?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I need my search code to search the customers table for a name that is identified with the "name" field of the workorders table.

Comment: This is pseudocode for what I want to happen, not "working" code.  I do not know the code I need to allow the search to happen for finding a customer attached to my workorder

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opnion at the table 'workorder' you should have the ID_CUSTOMER as your FK from table 'customers'.
Have that said, I made a example for you:

SELECT customers.firstname, customers.id, workorder.status
  FROM workorder INNER JOIN customers ON workorder.id_customer = customers.id;

Hope it helps you.

---

**If you looking for INSERT data from one table to another, you can use this example:**

INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field3,field9)
SELECT field3,field1,field4
FROM table2;

**But if you looking for INSERT in table CUSTOMER, use the example:**

INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

After you can INSERT a workorder using the customer name you choose.

---

I am not sure if I understoond your requirements, but if you need to fetch the last customer id entrace from page A and use it in the submission you do like:

```
// Select the last customerID entrance.
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$conn->exec($sql);
$customerID = $conn->lastInsertId();

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO workorder (date, name, installer, salesman, category, status) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
$q->execute(array($date,$customerID,$installer,$salesman,$category,$status));
```

Comment: I want to INSERT data, not READ it, how might I do that?

Comment: this will work for static form data, how can I implement to add the value of $id from the prior page as follows : customer.id = $id = workorder.name

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding your problem. Let me try to clearify. You have page A where person 1 will insert information about CUSTOMER, than person 1 will be redirect to page B where he/she will enter information about WORKORDER. Than you need to get the registered ID from page A and use it on the insert of page B ?

Comment: If you rather contact me at hangout - diogocostaferraz@gmail.com, then you can show me you project and I give you a better inside about it.